# SSRS Raport dosn't show in ReportViewer using EntityFramwork DataSource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, reporting-services, webforms, reportviewer

I want to make reporting page using SSRS rdlc in ReportViewer Control

here my ReportViewer code

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Height="510px" Width="978px">
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Then here my control code

```
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms

Public Class ReporingForm
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("Reporting.rdlc")
        Dim entities As DepenseEntities = New DepenseEntities
        Dim datasource As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("Dossiers", (From dossier In entities.Dossier.Take(10) Select dossier))
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I get no execution error, but my ReportViewer Keep Refreshing in infinite loop

here my result web page

[image]

Note that i'm using MVC Application in my project and WebForm for reportViewer

Could annyone have solution to this issue ?
How could i convert the EF datasource to Datasource using DataSet

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
            Dim report = New LocalReport()
report.SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(New PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted))
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("Reporting.rdlc")
Dim result = //get data from your entities into a list for example.
datasource = New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", result)
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource)
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
```

So, just filter your data from your entities into a list or so and it should work. I hope that this will help.